# Changing permission for EFI partition(FAT32)?

Tags: grub-efi

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot and it is directly going to Windows. I can't find option of Ubuntu in bios menu. But I can see Ubuntu folder in EFI partition when opened with adminstrator privileges.

Comment: What brand/model system? Are both Windows & Ubuntu installed in UEFI boot mode? Have you tried with Secure boot off? You should see ubuntu entry in UEFI boot menu, usually  f10 or f12.

Comment: Model : Sony Vaio. Yes both are in UEFI mode. Tried with secure boot off but not solved. No that's the problem. I can't find it in boot menu

Comment: Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789
Sony seems to need a work around. Most if dual booting, use the fallback or hard drive entry, not Ubuntu entry. And then the fallback uses /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which is the same as UEFI uses for all external drives, it just also can be used for internal drives.